# Подскажите не показывать в url product-category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

подскажите как в url не показывать product-category вот пример ссылки с которой нужно убрать:

https://nycb.riseservice.com.ua/product-category/wedding-dresses/the-collection-euphoria/

Вот так выглядят permalinks: http://joxi.ru/82QkxZ9FjLZv4r

Comment: Не надо этого делать: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/

Comment: Каждый раз об этом спрашивают, каждый раз одно и тоже отвечают и все равно люди не читают https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да Вы правы эту задачу поставили CEO-шники  , насчёт этого я сам читал и эти статьи (спасибо за них Вам). Но клиент хочет((( может всё таки есть какое то решение? на сайте использую ( плагин yoast premium)